# How to access an unknown enum's "valueOf()" method

Tags: java

I have configuration files which can be populated with enums and their respective values and will then be read by my program.

For example, a configuration file (yaml format) may look like this:

```yaml
SomeEnumClass:
- VALUE_A_OF_SOME_ENUM
- VALUE_B_OF_SOME_ENUM
- ANOTHER_VALUE

AnotherEnumClass:
- VALUE_1
- VALUE_3
- VALUE_3
- VALUE_7
[etc...]
```

Unfortunately this leads to duplication in my code (java) like this:

```java
if (enumNameString.equals("SomeEnumClass")) {
    Collection<SomeEnumClass> values = new ArrayList<>;
    for (String listEntry : yamlConfig.getStringList(enumNameString)) {
        values.add(SomeEnumClass.valueOf(listEntry));
    }
    return values;

} else if (enumNameString.equals("AnotherEnumClass")) {
    Collection<AnotherEnumClass> values = new ArrayList<>;
    for (String listEntry : yamlConfig.getStringList(enumNameString)) {
        values.add(AnotherEnumClass.valueOf(listEntry));
    }
    return values;

} else if ...
} else if ...
} else if ...
```

(please keep in mind that this example is pseudo code)

So of course i'm trying to get rid of the duplicate code. But how?
Is it possible to:

1. Get a class from a string? ("SomeEnumClass" -> SomeEnumClass.class)
2. Then check if that class is castable to Enum or something?
3. Access the enum's valueOf() method from that cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Map<String, Class<?>>` which contains the mapping like this:

```java
private static final Map<String, Class<Enum<?>>> MAP;
static {
    Map<String, Class<Enum<?>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(SomeEnumClass.class.getSimpleName(), SomeEnumClass.class);
    // your other enum classes

    MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

And then you can make use of `Enum.valueOf(Class<Enum>, String)`:

```java
Class<Enum<?>> enumClass = MAP.get(enumNameString);
if (enumClass != null) {
    Collection<Enum<?>> values = new ArrayList<>;
    for (String listEntry : yamlConfig.getStringList(enumNameString)) {
        values.add(Enum.valueOf(enumClass, listEntry));
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As usual, *all things reflection are typically evil*. However to get all the enum constants for a fully named class:

```
Class.forName(enumNameString).getEnumConstants()
```

`<T extends Enum<T> Enum.valueOf(Class<T>,String)` is great, but I don't know of a reasonable, obviously safe way to narrow a `Class<?>` to a `Class<T extends Enum<T>>` (`Class.asSubclass` will get you as far as `Class<T extends Enum>`).

Slightly better it to `switch` (or keep a `Map`) onto available constants:

```
    Enum<?>[] values = switch (enumNameString) {
        case "SomeEnumClass"    -> SomeEnumClass   .values();
        case "AnotherEnumClass" -> AnotherEnumClass.values();
        default -> throw new Error();
    };
    Enum<?> en = Arrays.stream(values)
        .filter(e -> e.name() == listEntry).findFirst().get();
```

If building a `Map` derived from classes, it may be easier to use `EnumSet.allOf(Class<?>)` than `MyEnum.values()`, `Enum.valueOf()` or `Class.getEnumConstants()`

Comment: Note that this will only work when the `enumNameString` contains the FQDN of the class.